# How can i disable video content in firefox?

Tags: firefox

I want all video content to be blocked in firefox, i.e. so that videos don't work at all.

When i tried to disable javascript in firefox in about:config, video content didn't worked. But can i disable video content without javascript disabling? Can I disable video content via about:config? And if so, what do I need to do there? Or Is there another way to disable video content?

Answer (score 0):

None of the `about:config` settings I tried seem to have any effect. But I was able to hide videos using custom css via extension https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customcss-injector/

Adding the following:

```css
video {
    display: none !important;
}
```

will hide all video elements.

They will still be playing, but not visible. Since they don't tend to autoplay audio, this might work out fine.

Another approach is to use JavaScript to remove the video elements:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('video').forEach(element => element.remove())
```

Note that `<video>` elements that load dynamically might not be selected by such a script, which is one reason you might prefer the css approach. Or even combine them :)

For a similar question with some solutions available, check out https://superuser.com/questions/670214/how-can-i-disable-html5-content-in-popular-browsers-like-firefox-and-chrome